# Writing dirty block from GDALRasterBand::IRasterIO` even with `LibTiff` > 4.0 on Windows and Mac but not Linux

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I am using Python `rasterio` to compress some large GeoTIFF imagery files. By large I mean 2-3 GB compressed, or on the order of 60,000 x 60,000 pixels each. I am hitting an error with `BIGTIFF` that should have been resolved since I am using `Libtiff` greater than 4.0, but the compression process is crashing on large files on Windows and Mac. So I followed the advice of [An error occurred while writing a dirty block from GDALRasterBand::IRasterIO](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368251).

I am using `rasterio` 1.1.7, and `Gdal` 3.1.2, and `LibTiff` 4.1.0. The code I am using for compression is below, and the error message is below as well. Note I am also using "windowed" writing to help avoid loading all of the data into memory--so I should not be hitting memory constraints that way.

```
dat = 'sample_image_big.tif'
target_file = 'sample_image_big_compressed_jpeg.tif'

with rasterio.Env():

    profile.update(
        compress="JPEG",
        BIGTIFF = "YES")

    with rasterio.open(target_file, 'w', **profile) as dst:
        for ji, window in dat.block_windows(1):
            dst.write(dat.read(window=window), window=window)
```

And here is the corresponding error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rasterio/_io.pyx", line 1369, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.write
  File "rasterio/shim_rasterioex.pxi", line 133, in rasterio._shim.io_multi_band
  File "rasterio/_err.pyx", line 182, in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_int
rasterio._err.CPLE_AppDefinedError: An error occurred while writing a
dirty block from GDALRasterBand::IRasterIODuring handling of the above
exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call
last):
  File "/Users/user/mdconda/anaconda3/envs/nyuki-env/bin/nyuki", line
10, in <module>
    sys.exit(nyuki())
  File "/Users/user/mdconda/anaconda3/envs/nyuki-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/mdconda/anaconda3/envs/nyuki-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/user/mdconda/anaconda3/envs/nyuki-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/user/mdconda/anaconda3/envs/nyuki-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/user/mdconda/anaconda3/envs/nyuki-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/user/mdconda/anaconda3/envs/nyuki-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/mdconda/anaconda3/envs/nyuki-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nyuki/nyuki.py",
line 160, in compress
    compressor(sourcetiff, target_compression, yes)
  File "/Users/user/mdconda/anaconda3/envs/nyuki-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nyuki/geotiff_compressor.py",
line 52, in compressor
    dst.write(dat.read(window=window), window=window)
  File "rasterio/_io.pyx", line 1371, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.write
rasterio.errors.RasterioIOError: Read or write failed. An error
occurred while writing a dirty block from GDALRasterBand::IRasterIO
```

If anyone wants the actual test image, they can pull it at this [link](https://github.com/00krishna-tools/nyuki/releases/download/v0.0.1/sample_image_big.tif). I am not sure what the problem is. I am using a "windowed" read and write to conserve memory. The hard disk has 100 GB of space, so no problem there.

What is this error indicating and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do I read right that you want to write the GeoTIFF without internal tiling?

Comment: Sorry if I was in any way unclear. So I open the file and then write it immediately with a different compression standard. I do "window" over the file, so I do perform internal tiling. I need the tiling, otherwise such large files can blow the available RAM.

Comment: That's why I asked, GeoTIFF with 60000 pixel wide stripes is heavy. Just to confirm, does windowing mean automatically the same than the creation option TILED=YES when gdal_translate and GeoTIFF driver is used, without a need to tell it in the profile?

Comment: @user30184 that is a good question. The Rasterio docs say this https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html, but I would have to check the source code to see whether "TILED=YES" is the same as windowing. Do you think that the window size being too large could be causing the issue, even with BIGTIFF support enabled?

Comment: If you do not generate the output as tiled you generate it as striped, a few 60000 pixels wide rows in each block.

Comment: @user30184 This is very helpful. Interesting, I was looking at a different section of the Rasterio docs and it shows that I can use something like this: `with rasterio.open("output.tif", 'w', **src.meta, compress="JPEG", tiled=True, blockxsize=256, blockysize=256) as dataset: # Write data to the file` So seems like I can force tiling, perhaps I can try that.

Comment: That's a good thing but should be irrelevant. Bigtiff is relevant at 4GB. Does your code succeed if you leave out the BIGTIFF option?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I can give it a try without the BIGTIFF option and see what happens. I don't have a windows computer myself, so I have to get my collaborator to try it on his machine.